# [react-native]gradlew assembleRelease --debug build successful but gradlew assembleRelease build failed

Tags: android, react-native

A crazy problem, when I run gradlew assembleRelease,the error message is :

```
...
Loading dependency graph, done.easeJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: xxx\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release\index.android.bundle
bundle: Copying 5 asset files
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Done copying assets

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to process incoming event 'ProgressComplete ' (ProgressCompleteEvent)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

there are some proguard's warning messages such as duplicate class,etc, I have resoved these warning messages, but it still builds failed.When I add --debug, it builds successful, crazy!!!

```
...
16:53:42.799 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :react-native-image-picker:assembleRelease (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
16:53:42.799 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 59.019 secs, idle: 0.031 secs
16:53:42.799 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter] Timing: Executing the DAG took 59.79 secs
16:53:42.799 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
16:53:42.809 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
16:53:42.809 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
16:53:42.809 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 1 mins 17.957 secs
```

last update:
If I paused the building process and wait for a moment to continue,it builds successful, I have set SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to 30, it seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem never occurs when using Gradle with the following switche:

```
gradlew assembleRelease --console plain
```

Comment: build generated but app crashing after install on device on start activity